# Ask "Save or Discard edits" to user that has manipulated a Glamour Text or Smalltalk code presentation

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, moose-technology

If i show a

- [Text presentation](http://www.themoosebook.org/book/internals/glamour/presentations/text) or a
- [Smalltalk code presentation](http://www.themoosebook.org/book/internals/glamour/presentations/smalltalk-code)

in a [Glamour browser](http://www.themoosebook.org/book/internals/glamour), can i make sure that the user does not inadvertently loose her/his edits by asking a "Save or Discard edits" dialog when the user leaves this presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at this point in time.